# Immediately initialize UIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uiimage

I have an array of UIImage objects as follows:

```
frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[sortedArray count]];
for (int nDx = 0; nDx < [sortedArray count]; nDx++)
{
    NSString * sImageName = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:nDx];
    [frames addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", imageFolderPath, sImageName]]];
}
```

In my timer method I am doing the following to cycle through the images:

```
self.image = [frames objectAtIndex:currentFrame];
currentFrame++;
if (currentFrame >= [frames count]) currentFrame = 0;
```

However, when I start the timer the images cycle slow the first time, and then everything works as expected.  I have also tried this without a timer.

How can I pre-load the images so they are ready to go when my timer starts?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate thread to load the images, using [this](https://gist.github.com/1144242) code.

If it works I'll add it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here img_array is UIImageView

```
 img_array.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_1.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_2.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_3.png"],nil];


 [img_array.animationImages setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VAL];
 img_array.animationImages .animationDuration = 4;
 [img_array.animationImages startAnimating]; 
 [self.view addSubview:img_array]
```

Try this: